# Dictionary returns different values when accessed from different functions

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**MINIMAL EXAMPLE**

Put a print inside the get_tuple_space function:

```
def get_tuple_space():
    global tuple_space
    print("VALUE INSIDE GETTER")
    print(tuple_space)
    return tuple_space
```

When I call this function inside the file server.py where the tuple_space is declared an it's defined I get the expected result, that is the tuple_space filled with some elements.

```
while True:
        # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
        readable,writable,exceptional = select.select(connected_list,[],[])

        for sock in readable:
            #New connection
            if sock == server_socket:
                connect()

            #Some incoming message from a client
            else:
                handle_incoming_msg(sock)
                print("Trying to get tuple space inside server")
                print(get_tuple_space())
```

However, trying to call this function in my client.py as following gives me and empty dictionary:

```
import socket, select, string, sys
import server

#some code
#...
#...

while True:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, client_socket]

        # Get the list of sockets which are readable
        rList, wList, error_list = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

        for sock in rList:
            #user entered a message
            msg=sys.stdin.readline()
            linda.blog_out(my_name, my_topic, msg, client_socket)

            #HERE
            print("trying to get tuple space inside client")
            print(server.get_tuple_space())

            #reads from topic
            messages = linda.blog_rd(my_topic)
            print messages
```

**END OF MINIMAL EXAMPLE**

**UPDATE**

Added "global tuple_space" in the functions that uses this dictionary. Also, I tried to call get_tuple_space inside my server code and it returned a correct value. Looks like the problem occurs when I call the function from another code.

**END OF UPDATE**

I'm having a probably very beginer problem with Python. I'm trying to do some code using sockets and dictionaries but strangely to me my dict returns filled in some functions and empty in another functions. I've made him global, so I was expecting it to returns filled in all my functions.

I believe I'm missing some information about python scope or something. It seems that everything related to the sockets are working fine.

Firstly, my dictionary is initialized in the server.py as following

```
tuple_space={}
```

After that, for example, the first function connects the client to the server socket and receives a message containing it's name, topic of interest and message written. Then, my program updates de tuple_space dictionary with some information. The second function does a very similar thing, updating the tuple_space dictionary with new messages from that client about that topic.

Both returns the most updated version of my dictionary and are running in my server code.

```
def connect():

    sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()

    data =str(sockfd.recv(buffer))
    name, topic, msg = data.split("@")

    connected_list.append(sockfd)
    tuple_space[(name, topic)]=""

    #add name and address
    registered_names.append(name)

    tuple_space[(name,topic)] = msg


def handle_incoming_msg(sock):
    # Data from client
    data = sock.recv(buffer)

    name, topic, msg = data.split("@")

    tuple_space[(name, topic)] = msg

    print(tuple_space)
```

Both functions are used in my main inside server.py. The first one when a new client connects and sends his name, topic and message, the second one when a connect client sends something:

```
def main():
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(10) #listen atmost 10 connection at one time

    # Add server socket to the list of readable connections
    connected_list.append(server_socket)
    print("Servidor inicializado\n")

    while True:
        # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
        readable,writable,exceptional = select.select(connected_list,[],[])

        for sock in readable:
            #New connection
            if sock == server_socket:
                connect()

            #Some incoming message from a client
            else:
                handle_incoming_msg(sock)

    server_socket.close()
```

After that, I want to receive the last messages, stored in tuple_space, in my client.py code. Here is what I'm doing inside a loop in my client:

```
messages_list = linda.blog_rd(my_topic)
            if len(messages_list)>0:
                print(messages_list)
```

The blog_rd function is the following, defined in my class "Linda"

```
def blog_rd(self, topic):

        incoming_messages = []

        registered_names = get_registered_names()
        tuple_space = get_tuple_space()

        for i in range(len(registered_names)):
            name = registered_names[i]
            print(name)
            incoming_messages.append((name, tuple_space[(name,topic)]))

        return incoming_messages
```

It was suposed to get the registered names and get the messagens stored in tuple_space, that call the get_tuple_space function.

The problem starts here:

```
def get_tuple_space():
    print(tuple_space)
    return tuple_space
```

When I call this function, the tuple_space dictionary, that is global, returns empty. It also happens with the registered_names list. I'm created that post about the dictionary to simplify my explanation, as the error in registered_names is the same as in tuple_space.

In my project, this function is called on another code file, acessed via import of the server.py. But what is confusing me is that even in the print the tuple_space is empty.

I was expecting that it would print all the values stored, as It does in the previous two functions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't show how the functions are called, so it's hard to know what's going on.  You need to explain the sequence of calls.  Also, you don't even show where `tuple_space` is defined.

Comment: Ok, added more info.

Comment: Is it really called server.cpp?

Comment: Can you reduce this to a *minimal* example? Instead of having a bunch of different functions and a server, can you simulate the same issue by just writing to the dictionary?

Comment: What is your actual vs expected output?

Comment: Tried a minimal example. @MadPhysicist

Comment: A minimal example is something that I can paste into my editor and hit run to exhibit the problematic behavior. I have no idea how you expect me to run that example. Why do you need a server for this question. Please reduce the problem to something simpler.

Comment: Also, why is your file called server.cpp?

Comment: server.cpp was a typo. It actually is server.py. Sorry for the bad minimal example. I couldn't give you something simpler. When you asked, I tried to write a program that declares and uses a dictionary in a file, let's say file1.py. and a file2.py uses that dictionary after file1.py modified it. I did as @gaFF said and it worked in that minimal example, but not on the real problem. So i though it has something to do with the sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for everyone who tried to help.

As I said, I was having some trouble giving a minimal example as in my minimal example without sockets it worked with your suggestions, but didn't worked in the real project.

What I did to solve was to change how I represent tuple_space. I made it a Class with the needed attributes, that before was into a dictionary. So the server.py uses the object and handles it depending on the messages sended from the server.

Not sure what was hapenning before, but I'm glad I solved the problem somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, `tuple_space` is declared in a file, and used in one or several others. But all variable in Python are enclosed in the namespace of their module (the file where it is created). So if `tuple_space` is declared in `server.py`, you have to import it in another file with `from server import tuple_space`.

Comment: Hi, gaFF. Tried this, but still not working. I've made this import in my Linda class file and tried to print the value of tuple_space inside blog_rd, but I'm still getting the empty dictionary.

Comment: As and additional info, the tuple_space is never accessed on the second file. What I do is to call a function in the second file that is defined in the first file where tuple_space is declared as global, that returns tuple_space.

Comment: Try remove any `global` ? Ensure the `from server import tuple_space` is present in all files using `tuple_space` ? Search for name shadowing ? It seems that `tuple_space = get_tuple_space()` could reuse the same name. Hard to say without the file structure and all the use of the name `tuple_space`.

Comment: Lets say I have file1 and file2. Tuple_space is declared in file1 and so is a function that returns tuple_space, get_tuple_space. In the file2, tuple_space is never called, both only the get_tuple_space is called. The problem is that the return of this function in the file2 is always an empty dictionary. But, if I try to use this function in the file1 it gives me the actual tuple_space.

Comment: But what about the functions `connect` and `handle_incoming_msg` ?

Comment: They are both in the same file where tuple_space is declared.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, sorry. Maybe a use of `tuple_space` not detailed here, try to do a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help. I remodeled my project and made it work :]